# QWindow QT::WA_NoSystemBackground attribute

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Is there a way to tell QWindow to use no background like for QWidget? I have a widget which I use with my own context for rendering. I use WA_NosystemBackground option for QWidget and I want to do the same with QWindow. However I couldn't find a way to tell Qt not to use a default background.

Comment: How are you creating the window's surface?

Comment: I am not creating Surface manually, so surface is the one that is created by default.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? No surface is created by default. Can you pastebin your code and explain HOW are you using a QWindow?

Comment: Aha! I didn't know that, I thought when I create a QWindow it creates a surface by default, it's good to know than. But still which parameters should I use for the surface for no background?

Comment: Are you creating an OpenGL surface? Then create a QSurfaceFormat with an alpha channel AND use a compositing WM. See also https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28214

Comment: Yes I know this bug, becaues of this bug I decided to try a different approach, I am trying to render my opengl engine output to QWindow as background, and than let QT render QML output to same QWindow, this way my goal is to combine my render engine with qml. Do you think is it possible?

Comment: Did you check the [official example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html)?